# How to convert serialClob to String format?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jdbc, jdbc-odbc

I am trying to convert serialclob to string. But I am not successful. I think I am not doing in the correct way. My code is:

```
char[] buffer;
        int count = 0;
        int length = 0;
        String data = null;
        String[] type;
        StringBuffer sb;
        try{
            SqlRowSet rows = getJdbcTemplate().queryForRowSet("select c.BOUNDING_BOX.GET_WKT() BOUNDING_BOX FROM EXAMPLE c WHERE EXAMPLE_ID = 100",
                    new Object[] {subid});
            SubscriptionModel subscription = new SubscriptionModel();
            System.out.println("bbox");
            SqlRowSetMetaData rsmd = rows.getMetaData();
                type = new String[rsmd.getColumnCount()];
                for(int col=0;col<rsmd.getColumnCount();col++)
                    type[col] = rsmd.getColumnTypeName(col + 1);
                System.out.println("Read rows and only serial clob data type values");
            while(rows.next()){
                System.out.println("test 1 here");
                for(int col=0;col<rsmd.getColumnCount();col++){
                    System.out.println("test 2 here");
                    if("CLOB".equals(type[col]){
                        System.out.println("test 3 here");
                        SerialClob clob = (SerialClob) ((ResultSet) rows).getClob(col + 1);
                        if(clob != null){
                            System.out.println("clob is not null");
                            Reader is = clob.getCharacterStream();

                            sb = new StringBuffer();
                            length = (int) clob.length();

                            if(length>0){
                                buffer = new char[length];
                                count = 0;
                                try{
                                    while((count = is.read(buffer)) != -1)
                                        sb.append(buffer);

                                    data = new String(sb);
                                }catch(Exception e){

                                }
                            }
                            else
                                data = (String) null;
                        }else
                            data = (String) null;
                    }else{
                        data = (String) rows.getObject(col + 1);
                    }
                }
            }
            return subscription;
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But I am getting an error like:

```
bbox
Read rows and only serial clob data type values
test 1 here
test 2 here
java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.sql.rowset.serial.SerialClob cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well this is at least one problem:

```
if(type[col] == "CLOB")
```

That's comparing string references directly. I suspect this would work better:

```
if ("CLOB".equals(type[col]))
```

That will get you into the right `if` block. I haven't looked in detail at the rest of your code - it would be simpler to read and maintain if you could break it up into smaller methods.

Comment: Thank for you quick reply.It helped me.But now another error is showing like:bbox
Read rows and only serial clob data type values
test 1 here
test 2 here
test 3 here
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.jdbc.support.rowset.ResultSetWrappingSqlRowSet cannot be cast to java.sql.ResultSet

Comment: @Kiran: You've got a *lot* of casts in your code. That's generally a code smell. Now that we can see you're using the Spring SqlRowSet, I suspect you can just use `getString`... it's worth a try, at least.

Comment: @Kiran: What do you mean by "it is also retrieving values as serialclob"? To be honest, if you're new to Java you should stay away from JDBC to start with - become familiar with the language and core platform first and *then* move on to things like JDBC. Otherwise you'll just be trying things without knowing whether the problem is something API-specific (as this *might* be) or due to a general lack of Java experience (as your first problem was).

Comment: ok i will learn java concepts.If we use getString.. we are getting serialclob values.And you mentioned that problem was API-Specific.Can't we solve this one?

Comment: @Kiran: What *exactly* do you mean by "we are getting serialclob values" - getString returns a string; what's in that string?

Comment: We tried this way subscription.setbBox(rows.getString("BOUNDING_BOX")); But we are getting output: javax.sql.rowset.serial.SerialClob@7965c5

Comment: @Kiran: Right, fine. In that case you may need to call `rows.GetObject(...)` and cast to `Clob`. (You shouldn't cast to `SerialClob`; just `Clob` is enough.)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is most likely here --

```
if(type[col] == "CLOB"){ // <-- This does Object equality
```

Use String#equals() method to do String comparisons.

```
if ( "CLOB".equals(type[col]) ) {
```

Comment: Thank for you quick reply.It helped me.But now another error is showing like:
org.springframework.jdbc.support.rowset.ResultSetWrappingSqlRowSet cannot be cast to java.sql.ResultSet

Comment: The `SqlRowSet` in Spring does not extend java.sql.ResultSet. So you cannot do the cast like you are doing in your code. Instead receive it as `ResultSetWrappingSqlRowSet` and then do a `rows.getResultSet()` to get a handle on the java.sql.ResultSet